# Empty fields after proguard optimization of JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, proguard

I am trying to use proguard to obfuscate a Java application that uses JAXB.  The code (which uses a publicly available library) is

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import org.cansas.cansas1d.SASdataType;
import org.cansas.cansas1d.SASentryType;
import org.cansas.cansas1d.SASentryType.Run;
import org.cansas.cansas1d.SASrootType;


public class CansasReader {
    
    private static final String RES_DIR = "/Users/paul/Documents/sample data/ZZ Non-2D formats/canSAS/";
    private static final String JAXB_CONTEXT = "org.cansas.cansas1d";

    private JAXBContext jc;
    private JAXBElement<SASrootType> xmlJavaData;
    
    /**
     * Open a cansas1d 1D file
     *
     * @param xmlFile
     * @return SasRootType object (saves a second method call)
     * @throws JAXBException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    public SASrootType loadXML(String xmlFile) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
        jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXB_CONTEXT);      // reference the namespace: 
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(xmlFile));
        xmlJavaData = (JAXBElement<SASrootType>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(in);
        return xmlJavaData.getValue();
    }

    /**
     * Describe the XML data in more detail than toString() method
     * and print to stdout.
     */
    public void full_report(SASrootType srt) {
        for ( SASentryType entry : srt.getSASentry() ) {
            System.out.println("SASentry");
            System.out.printf("Title:\t%s\n", entry.getTitle());
            List<SASentryType.Run> runs = entry.getRun();
            System.out.printf("#Runs:\t%d\n", runs.size());
            for ( Run run : runs ) {
                System.out.printf("Run@name:\t%s\n", run.getName());
                System.out.printf("Run:\t%s\n", run.getValue());
            }
            List<SASdataType> datasets = entry.getSASdata();
            System.out.printf("#SASdata:\t%d\n", entry.getSASdata().size());
            for ( SASdataType sdt : datasets ) {
                System.out.printf("SASdata@name:\t%s\n", sdt.getName());
                System.out.printf("#points:\t%d\n", sdt.getIdata().size());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

     

    /**
     * simple representation of data in memory
     */
    public String toString(SASrootType sasRoot) {
        return "SASentry elements: " + sasRoot.getSASentry().size();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("class: " + CansasReader.class.getCanonicalName());
        String[] fileList = {
            RES_DIR + "cs_collagen.xml",
            RES_DIR + "1998spheres.xml",
            "cannot_find_this.xml"
        };
        for (String xmlFile : fileList) {
            System.out.println("\n\nFile: " + xmlFile);
            try {
                CansasReader rdr = new CansasReader();
                SASrootType srt = rdr.loadXML(xmlFile);
                System.out.println(rdr.toString(srt));
                rdr.full_report(srt);
                System.out.println("the end.");

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found:" +  xmlFile);
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                System.out.println("Could not open (unmarshall) XML file" +  xmlFile);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The proguard config file is

```
-injars  CansasReader.jar
-outjars CansasReader_ob.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-printmapping CansasReader.map
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod, Signature
-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}
-repackageclasses ''
-overloadaggressively
-defaultpackage ''
-allowaccessmodification
-keeppackagenames org.cansas.cansas1d
-keepparameternames
-keep,includedescriptorclasses public  class org.cansas.cansas1d.package-info
-keep,includedescriptorclasses public class org.cansas.cansas1d.FloatUnitType
(and the same for every other class in the package)
-keep,includedescriptorclasses public class CansasReader
```

Before obfuscating, the output is as expected.  After obfuscating, I don't get any exceptions, but expected data fields are null.  For example, the output

> File: /Users/paul/Documents/sample data/ZZ Non-2D
> formats/canSAS/cs_collagen.xml SASentry elements: 1 SASentry
> Title:    dry chick collagen, d = 673 A, 6531 eV, X6B
>
> ## Runs:    1 Run@name:  Run:   Sep 19 1994     01:41:02 am
>
> ## SASdata: 1 SASdata@name:
>
> ## points:  125

After obfuscation becomes:

> File: /Users/paul/Documents/sample data/ZZ Non-2D
> formats/canSAS/cs_collagen.xml SASentry elements: 1 SASentry
> Title:    null
>
> ## Runs:    0
>
> ## SASdata: 0

Note that, following other suggestions on this list, I did include both Signature and *Annotation* in the config file.  That prevents the type cast exceptions I was getting before, but the xml file is still not being read in properly.  Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: As you (un)marshal the SAS objects from a  publicly available library: can't you exclude this library from the obfuscation?

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing when I told proguard to explicitly keep all the classes in the library.  Is there a better way to do this?  My ultimate goal is to create a jar file that can be used by others who have not downloaded the public library, so I'd like my jar file to include everything necessary to run.

Comment: Possibly you need a stronger "antidote", such as -keepclasseswithmembers. JAXB accesses these by reflection.

Comment: Hmm, thanks.  It appears to me that -keepclasseswithmembers actually isn't as powerful as plain old -keep?  Anyhow, I tried that, doesn't seem to help.  Also tried explicitly listing fully qualified classes inside the -keep.  And adding a -printseeds  command gives the full list of all methods within all classes.  I'm wondering if the annotations are not being properly preserved even though I had -keepattributes   \*Annotation\* ?  Is there any way to check?  it seems as though introspection (an approach with which I am much less familiar than freflection) is used extensively by JAXB.

Comment: Update:  nothing I have done seems to work to make proguard play nicely with JAXB using this public library.  (And, really my goal is to obfuscate not just this test case but a much larger application).  But I found a workaround: obfuscate the jar file using proguard and keeping everything to do with cansas public and un-obfuscated, and then use
jar -ufv CansasReader.jar org
to replace the the modified classes with the original unobfuscated classes.  That works...although I really wish I could see how to do it without that step.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to try the JAXB user list users@jaxb.java.net which isn't very active but should have a few people with specific JAXB experience listening. - Also, deploying your app as a couple of jars (one obfuscated, one not) might not be too much of a PITA for your users.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I don't actually distribute my app as a jar, it is just an app (cross-platform Mac, PC, Linux) so making my users download a separate jar and put it in a specific place might very well be perceived as a PITA.  But at least I have a functioning workaround.

Answer (score 2):

```
-keep public class your.package.path.to.jaxb.classes.** {
  public protected private *;
}
```

This should help. I guess you've already found your solution. Best regards. Ralph.